# Segmentation fault when using fscanf, trouble debugging after using valgrind

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I've cut out the code that works so the code below is not a whole program but the problematic part.

I get a segmentation fault on the fscanf line below. I added the character width for each variable to try and fix it so I don't understand why it would seg fault.

I read from a CSV file into an array of structs.

My main is just this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    menu();
}
```

Then menu.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "DatabaseOps.h"
#include "menu.h"
#define SIZE 1000 //max size assumed to be 1000
void menu()
{
    int j, lastID; //keeping track of id numbers used

    Person* persons;
    persons = (Person*)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(Person)); /*declaring array of person structs on the heap*/

    for(j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) /*initialise all IDs to -1*/
        {
        persons[j].ID = -1;
        }

    int option = 1;
    while (option!=7)
    {
        printf("1. Load Database\n");
        scanf("%d", &option);

        switch (option)
            {
            case 1:
            printf("\nLoading Database\n\n");
            lastID = loadDb(persons);
            break;

            default:
            printf("Invalid choice, please try again\n\n");
            break;
            }
    }
}
```

Persons is defined in menu.h like so:

```
typedef struct Person
    {
    int ID;
    int salary;
    int deleted;
    char salutation[4];
    char firstName[21];
    char surName[31];
    char job[16];
    } Person;
```

And then the DatabaseOps.c file that causes the error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "DatabaseOps.h"
#include "menu.h"

int loadDb(Person *inPersons)  //function reads csv file into an array of Employee structs
    {
    int i, newID = 0; /*declaring lastID counter to keep track of the last employee ID so that I can increment it when creating a new employee*/

    char* fileName = malloc( 100 * sizeof( char ));
    printf("Enter name of CSV file: ");
    scanf("%99s", fileName);

    FILE* f = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if(f==NULL)  /*If the file doesn't exist, return to menu*/
        {
        printf("Error: could not open file\n");
        }

    else
        { /*the fscanf function uses grouping by commas to seperate the CSV values - [^,]*/
        while(fscanf(f, "%d,%3[^,],%20[^,],%30[^,],%15[^,],%d,%d", &inPersons[i].ID, inPersons[i].salutation, inPersons[i].firstName, inPersons[i].surName, inPersons[i].job, &inPersons[i].salary, &inPersons[i].deleted)!=EOF)
            {
            newID = inPersons[i].ID; //Keeping track of the last used ID
            i++;
            }
        }
    fclose(f);

    return newID;
    }
```

Valgrind gives me this error, which I'm not sure how to interpret:

```
==19378== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==19378==    at 0x405A215: _IO_vfscanf (in /lib/libc-2.12.so)
==19378==    by 0x4067368: __isoc99_fscanf (in /lib/libc-2.12.so)
==19378==    by 0x80486E5: loadDb (DatabaseOps.c:25)
==19378==    by 0x80485B5: menu (menu.c:29)
==19378==    by 0x804852E: main (main.c:6)
==19378== 
==19378== Invalid write of size 4
==19378==    at 0x405A215: _IO_vfscanf (in /lib/libc-2.12.so)
==19378==    by 0x4067368: __isoc99_fscanf (in /lib/libc-2.12.so)
==19378==    by 0x80486E5: loadDb (DatabaseOps.c:25)
==19378==    by 0x80485B5: menu (menu.c:29)
==19378==    by 0x804852E: main (main.c:6)
==19378==  Address 0x9acac288 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==19378== 
==19378== 
==19378== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==19378==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x9ACAC288
==19378==    at 0x405A215: _IO_vfscanf (in /lib/libc-2.12.so)
==19378==    by 0x4067368: __isoc99_fscanf (in /lib/libc-2.12.so)
==19378==    by 0x80486E5: loadDb (DatabaseOps.c:25)
==19378==    by 0x80485B5: menu (menu.c:29)
==19378==    by 0x804852E: main (main.c:6)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int i, newID = 0; /*declaring lastID counter to keep track of the last employee ID so that I can increment it when creating a new employee*/
```

`i` needs to be initialized to 0.

Comment: Wow, that fixed it. Can't believe it was something so simple. I assumed that initializing like that initialized all variables on the line. Thank you.

Comment: @user2368481: You need to turn your compiler warnings up. Compile with `-std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror`, it'll tell you about things like this.

Comment: I will definitely do that in the future.